# How to make a circular contacts list using a recyclerview on an android round watch? See attached

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to make a circular contacts list using a recyclerview on an android round smartwatch but I want to add a header that shows like an alphabet marker based on the first name of the person. Its supposed to be scrolling on a circular motion also.

I attached a screenshot.This is from a Round Samsung Smartwatch. [Click for screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDtlm.png)

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.userName.text = list[position].name
        holder.contactNo.text = list[position].contactno
        holder.contactsInitial?.text = list[position].name?.substring(0,1)?.toUpperCase()
        val drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(contactsInitial, generator.randomColor)
        holder.initialBackground.setImageDrawable(drawable)
```

Comment: You would need to sort the list alphabetically by first name, then check if the 1st letter of the name you're putting on the list is the same as the previous one, if it is then don't add the header, if it is add a header to the new row.

Comment: Thank you for this! How do I sort the list alphabetically by its 1st letter?

Comment: Depends on the list, if the list is a custom object (looks like it is) you would need to make your own sorter.

Comment: Okay! I'll try to work on it. Thank you!